# IBM Watson Assistant - time duration entities

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-watson, watson-assistant

I am looking for a way to extract especially time durations as **entities**.

Is there any way to achieve this - right now time durations get mixed into other time entities...

Example:
**Schedule a meeting at 3pm for 30 minutes** 
Results in:

```
@sys-time:15:00:00
@sys-time:15:30:00
```

Expected behavior (e.g something like that):

```
@sys-time:15:00:00
@sys-time-duration:30; unit:minutes
```

Thanks in advance,
Jacky

Comment: Have you looked into the full returned data? There is metadata on what has been captured and more, including your 30 minutes.

Comment: @data_henrik thanks for your hint... I’ll look into it

Comment: @data_henrik do you have an idea why somehow e.g. "30 minutes" isn't recognized as time anymore ? - the system entity sys-time is still enabled of course

Comment: See here for the system entities and their attributes: https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/assistant?topic=assistant-system-entities#system-entities-sys-time Are you using a current API version? You are only showing parts of the data, please add all detected attributes